# is there a way to make advance payment for the Blaze plan in firebase?

Tags: firebase, hosting, blaze

We are setting up a website to be hosted on firebase, and we wanted to pay the hosting costs for two years in advance. Is there anyway to do this in the Blaze plan ? if not, what are the options to do this, can automatic charging from our account, say on paypal, can be arranged for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All billing for Firebase usage happens through Google Cloud's payment infrastructure. From a quick search, it seems that GCP supports [making manual payments or paying early](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/manual-payment).

It also seems that [PayPal is an accepted payment method](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/payment-methods#paypal):

> We accept PayPal as a payment method, [if supported in your country](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/resources/currency).

Comment: Thanks. I found that link too but it was not clear how early the payments could be. Can one have funds available in paypal enough to cover years of google cloud expenses ?